# texture procedural in AO

Tags: eevee-render-engine

How can I add a texture procedural to the AO of a material?
both on itself and on the objects the AO casts a shadow on? preferably with different textures for each channel ?

I want to make dirt that exists between two objects that are side by side on the EEVEE or bake in Ccycles to use it in EEVEE I want to use the AO result with a procedural texture to draw dirt

Comment: AO doesn't affect shadows; AO doesn't affect any object but the object it's on.  Meanwhile, AO doesn't mean anything anywhere except Eevee, where you have an AO input for Specular BSDF (where how to make procedural AO is trivial-- probably not what you're asking.)  What is your goal from AO?  Where are you rendering?  What is it you hope to achieve?

Comment: Don't tell me in comments.  Comments are temporary and people won't read them to answer your question.  Put it in your question.